# ArrayList keep returning 0

Tags: java, sql, arraylist

I retrieve the data from database and loop it thru an array to display the like amount.

```
        public void SetUpLikeAmount() {
    int likes = 0;
    ArrayList <Integer> likeArray = new ArrayList <Integer>();
    for (int count = 0; count < likeArray.size();count++){
    // Set Up Database Source
    db.setUp("IT Innovation Project");
    String sql = "Select likeDislike_likes from forumLikeDislike WHERE topic_id = "
            + topicId + "";
    ResultSet resultSet = null;
    // Call readRequest to get the result
    resultSet = db.readRequest(sql);
    try {
        while (resultSet.next()) {
            likeArray.add(Integer.parseInt(resultSet.getString("likeDislike_likes")));
            likes += likeArray.get(count);
        }
        resultSet.close();
    } catch (Exception e) {
        System.out.println(e);
    }

    }
    jLabel_like.setText(Integer.toString(likes));
}
```

However, it keeps returning 0. Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

May be here is the new code you should refer:

```
public void SetUpLikeAmount() {
     int likes = 0;
    // Set Up Database Source
    db.setUp("IT Innovation Project");
    String sql = "Select likeDislike_likes from forumLikeDislike WHERE topic_id = "
            + topicId + "";
    ResultSet resultSet = null;
    // Call readRequest to get the result
    resultSet = db.readRequest(sql);
    try {
        while (resultSet.next()) {
            likes += Integer.parseInt(resultSet.getString("likeDislike_likes"));
        }
        resultSet.close();
    } catch (Exception e) {
        System.out.println(e);
    }

    jLabel_like.setText(Integer.toString(likes));
}
```

You might not need the arraylist I believe as you are getting the value and summing it during the iteration over the result set only.

Comment: Yup but without arraylist, it is giving me too few parameters error

Comment: Can I write like this? likes += resultSet.getInt("likeDislike_likes"); Because my column is number

Comment: yes, that should work correctly if column is Number type in database

Comment: or on second thought you can get Sum from the query itself if nothing else is needed. Most DBs support this aggregate function.

Answer (score 5):

(As an aside, it never *returns* anything - you've posted a `void` method.)

Look at this code:

```
ArrayList <Integer> likeArray = new ArrayList <Integer>();
for (int count = 0; count < likeArray.size();count++){
    ...
}
```

You've just created a *new* `ArrayList<Integer>`, which will therefore have a size of 0. Therefore, the loop always completes immediately, without ever executing the body.

If you're trying to get input from a list created elsewhere, you should probably pass that into your method. (You should also use a `PreparedStatement` with a parameter instead of including the value directly in your SQL.)

Comment: What do you mean? Sorry I am quite new to this field

Comment: What do I mean about what? You create a new `ArrayList`. It's empty to start with, so its size is 0. Your loop condition checks whether `count` is less than the size... If you're *that* new to Java, you should really start off with the basics - forget about database access and even UIs to start with... learn the fundamentals of the language and core types (like collections) first.

Comment: I have no choice. This is my school project. So how can I fix it? Can you give me some example?

Comment: @Rauryn: You should take a step back, and study the basics carefully. There's no point in being given an answer to fixing this one problem if you still don't understand the fundamentals - you'll just get stuck again very soon, without having really learned anything. Anyway, we can't tell you how to fix it as you've given us no idea about what it's actually meant to do. But the loop that you've got is useless - what were you *trying* to loop over?

Comment: My project due on Monday and I just came out with this idea. I getting the data from database which I have no idea how big is the size of array. So i am using arrayList instead. Then I need loop thru to get the amount of column in database and sum it up.

Comment: @Rauryn: It sounds like you want to do *one* query then (before the loop) and then loop over the results. But I'm afraid I'm still certain that if you didn't understand why the loop wasn't working, you're really just not ready for database work. Your project deadline doesn't change that at all.

Answer (score 2):

You're iterating over the list `likeArray` which is empty.  So it won't enter the loop

Comment: So what so I do to fix it?

Comment: Remove that portion of the code from inside the for loop.  In this instance, it's useless

Comment: I need it to get the total amount of likes from database

Comment: I'm not going to complete your work for you.  It seems you don't understand the basics of Java.  I'd suggest you revisit the basics first before attempting something like this

Comment: You get the total by iterating through the resultset

Comment: remove this  for (int count = 0; count < likeArray.size();count++){

Comment: @DomV so you means I do not need the array list?